# Add a QScrollBar to cramped QWidget in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, qscrollarea

Update on a previous question.

When displaying this looks very cramped, see photo below.

[image]

I would like to keep the QWidget (panel) the same height, and add a QScrollBar to the right of it, so the widgets go their natural size and the user can just scroll down

I tried adding this code in.

```
scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
scroll.setWidget(widget)
scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
scroll.setFixedHeight(400)
layout.addWidget(scroll)
```

However the code runs, but no GUI even opens, so I to manually force stop it from the command line.

The working code is seen below.

Thanks

Rob

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from scapy.all import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
vbox1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

button = QPushButton("Send")

flag1 = QCheckBox("CWR")
flag2 = QCheckBox("ECN")
flag3 = QCheckBox("URG")
flag4 = QCheckBox("ACK")
flag5 = QCheckBox("PSH")
flag6 = QCheckBox("RST")
flag7 = QCheckBox("SYN")
flag8 = QCheckBox("FIN")

textEdit1 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')
textEdit2 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')
textEdit3 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')
textEdit4 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')
#textEdit5 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')#using check boxes instead
textEdit6 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')

def buildTCPPanal():
    label1 = QtGui.QLabel("IP Destanation Address")
    label2 = QtGui.QLabel("IP Source Address")
    label3 = QtGui.QLabel("Source Port")
    label4 = QtGui.QLabel("Destanation Port")
    label5 = QtGui.QLabel("Flags")
    label6 = QtGui.QLabel("Data")

    layout.addWidget(label1) #dest add
    layout.addWidget(textEdit1)

    layout.addWidget(label2) #src add
    layout.addWidget(textEdit2)

    layout.addWidget(label3) #src port
    layout.addWidget(textEdit3)

    layout.addWidget(label4) #dest port
    layout.addWidget(textEdit4)

    layout.addWidget(label5) #flags
    layout.addWidget(flag1)
    layout.addWidget(flag2)
    layout.addWidget(flag3)
    layout.addWidget(flag4)
    layout.addWidget(flag5)
    layout.addWidget(flag6)
    layout.addWidget(flag7)
    layout.addWidget(flag8)


    layout.addWidget(label6)
    layout.addWidget(textEdit6)

    runCommandButton = QPushButton("Send Packet")
    runCommandButton.setObjectName("runCommandButton")

    vbox1.addLayout(layout)
    vbox1.addWidget(runCommandButton)
    #QtCore.QObject.connect(runCommandButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), createScapyCommand)

    widget.setLayout(vbox1)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


buildTCPPanal()
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you going to show us where you tried it yourself?

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist, I have edited the question on what I have been trying. Thanks :)

Comment: You can edit your code since the indentation is very important in python

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, yes I'm aware of that, the indentation is fine, it's just the way it pasted out on StackOverflow

Comment: Have you noticed that `return page_4` at the same level as `def  buildTCPPanal`?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, it is not like that in the actual code, it's just what ever happened when I pasted it to StackOverflow.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: What kind of object is page_4? You have never created it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, the code seems to be running with it, but the GUI doesn't even open, it's just stuck in the terminal until I force close it.

Comment: @eyllanesc page_4 is a QWidget, the code that created it is not in my sample but is in my code

Comment: @RobGeraghty. Please edit this into your question. Your question should be standalone, with *all* relevant information. You should no require constant prodding from other users to make a good question according to site guidelines. While I realize that this is not always easy to do the first few times, please get in the habit.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done an entire update, hope this helps, thanks :)

Comment: Adding the code in where? Why not show us the complete code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new widget where you place the `QScrollArea`, and display that new widget. Also it is not good to combine elements of `PyQt4` with `PySide`. And another bad practice is to use elements in a function that are outside that scope.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


def buildTCPPanal():
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    vbox1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

    button = QtGui.QPushButton("Send")

    flag1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("CWR")
    flag2 = QtGui.QCheckBox("ECN")
    flag3 = QtGui.QCheckBox("URG")
    flag4 = QtGui.QCheckBox("ACK")
    flag5 = QtGui.QCheckBox("PSH")
    flag6 = QtGui.QCheckBox("RST")
    flag7 = QtGui.QCheckBox("SYN")
    flag8 = QtGui.QCheckBox("FIN")

    textEdit1 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')
    textEdit2 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')
    textEdit3 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')
    textEdit4 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')
    #textEdit5 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')#using check boxes instead
    textEdit6 = QtGui.QTextEdit('')

    label1 = QtGui.QLabel("IP Destanation Address")
    label2 = QtGui.QLabel("IP Source Address")
    label3 = QtGui.QLabel("Source Port")
    label4 = QtGui.QLabel("Destanation Port")
    label5 = QtGui.QLabel("Flags")
    label6 = QtGui.QLabel("Data")

    layout.addWidget(label1) #dest add
    layout.addWidget(textEdit1)

    layout.addWidget(label2) #src add
    layout.addWidget(textEdit2)

    layout.addWidget(label3) #src port
    layout.addWidget(textEdit3)

    layout.addWidget(label4) #dest port
    layout.addWidget(textEdit4)

    layout.addWidget(label5) #flags
    layout.addWidget(flag1)
    layout.addWidget(flag2)
    layout.addWidget(flag3)
    layout.addWidget(flag4)
    layout.addWidget(flag5)
    layout.addWidget(flag6)
    layout.addWidget(flag7)
    layout.addWidget(flag8)


    layout.addWidget(label6)
    layout.addWidget(textEdit6)

    runCommandButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Send Packet")
    runCommandButton.setObjectName("runCommandButton")

    vbox1.addLayout(layout)
    vbox1.addWidget(runCommandButton)
    #QtCore.QObject.connect(runCommandButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), createScapyCommand)

    widget.setLayout(vbox1)
    widget.show()

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
    scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()

    scroll.setWidget(widget)
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    scroll.setFixedHeight(400)
    layout.addWidget(scroll) 
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


buildTCPPanal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, work great. Also thanks for the coding tips, always appreciated.